# Possible bug in java.util.Set API

Tags: java, collections, javadoc, comparator

`java.util.Set` API states:

> sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2)

But as far as I understand `TreeSet` uses `Comparable/Comparator` to determine if e1 and e2 are duplicates. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

If `compareTo` is consistent with `equals` (which it should), it doesn't matter whether a TreeSet uses `compareTo` or `equals` to determine equality. From the JavaDoc:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator
>   for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so
>   because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation,
>   but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The
>   behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set
>   interface.

This program will print 'true', even though `equals` always returns false. But the bug would be in the fact the `compareTo` and `equals` are inconsistent for A, and is not a bug in TreeSet.

```
class A implements Comparable<A> {
    public int compareTo(A a) {
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<A> set = new TreeSet<A>();
        set.add(new A());
        System.out.println(set.contains(new A()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Very strange, assume you have a Dog class, and you want to sort your dogs by weight, then by height. Is it illegal? Does dog1.equals(dog2) make sense at all?

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev You can compare dogs by weight and height, but if there are other properties then any comparator/comparable should take them into account also, so it doesn't doesn't return 0 for dogs that are not equal.

Comment: OK, let's take people - nobody is equals, equals is just irrelevant. According to you when you want to compare peopse you are breaking some contracts.

Comment: If no objects are equal, then a comparator can just return -1 or 1. Comparables are always defined together with equals, you can't just separate them. A comparable saying that two people are equal is the same as equals saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong; TreeSet doesn't use Comparable/Comparator to determine if e1 is equal to e2. 
Equals method is part of Object class and used to decide if two elements of collection are same or not. i.e. e1.equals(e2)

But Comparable/Comparator interface is used to decide if an element is greater than, equal or less than other element. And this is used during sorting. So only thing you need to ensure is that equals and compareto methods are consistent.

**So to compare two objects equals method is used and comparator/comparable is used during sorting**

**EDIT**
Below is the method definition from JDK 6; equals method of AbstractSet. TreeSet extends AbstractSet

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
    if(obj == this)
        return true;
    if(!(obj instanceof Set))
        return false;
    Collection collection = (Collection)obj;
    if(collection.size() != size())
        return false;
    try
    {
        return containsAll(collection);
    }
    catch(ClassCastException classcastexception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch(NullPointerException nullpointerexception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html

Comment: TreeSet delegates to TreeMap which seems to use compareTo where equals would normally be used. See getEntry in http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/TreeMap.java.html

Comment: which method of TreeSet calls TreeMap ?

Comment: Every method calls TreeMap. A TreeSet is implemented as a TreeMap that ignores its values.

Comment: Agree that TreeSet internally uses Map; but it call equals method of AbstractSet for equality check.

Comment: That equals method is used to compare two Sets together, not two items within the set. The containsAll call in there still uses compareTo for each item.

Comment: think you have a point but need to research bit more...below link talks something similar https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2057888

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` use Comparator. Do you know it actually maintains elements by using map.

```
 public TreeSet() {
    this(new TreeMap<E,Object>());
 }
```

As you said *Sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2)*. That is why Comparator has `equals` method.

No matter how we are going to use `Set` it depends with `Comparator`. If we use our own comparator, we can use `Set` as `List` but normally we don't do that. If we add our own Object in to `TreeSet` must pass `Comparator` when initializing `TreeSet` or object must be implemented by `Comparable`

**Comparable**
 
 A comparable object having capability to compare itself with another object

**Comparator**
 Used for comparing two different objects.

```
public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
    // if sort by name
    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
 }


 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // equals with ID
        Employee e = (Employee)obj;
        return this.getId().equals(e.getId());
 }
```

Here is [Java Sorting: Comparator vs Comparable](http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html) a tutorial.